# How compatible are psycopg and Plone 5 and what should one pay attention to?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, plone, zope

I would like to use the Python library [psycopg](https://www.psycopg.org) in a Plone 5 project to retrieve the triggers from the database (PostgreSQL 12).

My first naive idea with psycopg in pure Python and psycopg 2 2.9.1:

```
connection.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
   cur = connection.cursor()
   cur.execute("LISTEN new_Id;")

while True:
    select.select([connection], [], [])
    connection.poll()
    connection.commit()

    while connection.notifies:
        notify = connection.notifies.pop()
        print("Got NOTIFY:", notify.pid, notify.channel, notify.payload)
```

Therefore I would like to know if this library can be used in Plone 5/Zope 4 and if this is possible what should be considered ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [zope.sqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/zope.sqlalchemy/). It is a wrapper around [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) with an integration to the Zope transaction system. For PostgreSQL you still need a database driver ([psycopg2 is possible](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2)).

Here is a simple example:

```py
from zope.sqlalchemy import register
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
import transaction

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@localhost/test")

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
register(DBSession)

session = DBSession()

result = session.execute("DELETE FROM objects WHERE id=:id", {"id": 2})
row = result.fetchone()

transaction.commit()
```

Comment: Hello @Tom and thank you for your feedback :-)

But if I "only" want to evaluate the PosgreSQL triggers, like in my example from my original question. Do I still need the library zope.sqlalchemy ?

Comment: Hello @ChsharpNewbie you should be able to use the library standalone. You need to take extra care with transactions, because you have two systems then. Have you tried your code? Is there anything which is *not* working as expected?

Comment: Hi @Tom, I asked this question some time ago to hear what to consider between the python library psycopg 2 and Zope/Plone 5, in the meantime I have tested it and it seems to work. In my project I don't write anything with Plone/Zope into the PosgeSQL database, I do that with another system. I only want to "monitor" the database in Plone/Zope, I thought psycopg might be an idea